# How to replace an integer in an object and save it to the mongodb database

Tags: node.js, mongoose, discord.js

I'm trying to increase the amount integer in the "Axe" object without changing the amount integer in the "Sword" object and saving it to the database using mongoose. How can I do this? Currently my JSON object looks like:

```json
{
"ID": "63810976291863247",
"XP": 0,
"Level": 1,
"Cash": 700,
"Bank": 1000,
"Inventory": [{"name":"Axe","amount":3},{"name":"Sword","amount":"2"}]
}
```

I tried fetching the amount, adding the currently amount by 1, and this is where I'm stuck. When I tried $push and $set queries, it made a result that I didn't want.

```js
for (key of user.Inventory) {

          var newAmount = picked.amount + 1;
          var picked = user.Inventory.find(o => o.name === 'Axe');
    
          }
    
          const newItem = {
            name: picked.name,
            amount: newAmount
          }
    
          User.findOneAndUpdate(
            {
              ID: interaction.user.id
            },
            {
              $set: {
                Inventory: newItem,
              },
            },
            {
              upsert: true,
              useFindAndModify: false,
            },
            (e, d) => {
              if (e) return console.error(e);
            }
          );

user.save()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: To change it just use `<Object>.<Key> = <New_Value>` but first make that in a real object with `JSON.parse(<Object>)`, for the mongodb, that I don't know, I've never used it

Comment: For example, you want to change the name Axe, to do that use `<Main_Object>.Inventory[0].name = <New_Name>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it by using the [`$inc`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator:

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    ID: interaction.user.id,
    'Inventory.name': 'Axe'
  },
  {
    $inc: {
      'Inventory.$.amount': 1
    },
  },
  {
    upsert: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  },
  (e, d) => {
    if (e) return console.error(e);
  }
);
```